# issue regarding install curl on linux mint

Tags: php, linux, linux-mint

I have a Linux Mint machine I am working on. I want Laravel to install on it.

When I search for this I got this command: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php from "https://getcomposer.org/download/" to put in terminal but it gives me this:

```
The program 'php' is 
currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After i have done sudo apt-get install curl

```
libcurl3 curl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libcurl3 i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main curl i386 7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.27.0-1ubuntu1.9_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

got this which is not successfully installed curl

How can any one I successfully install these things and Composer and Laravel?
Please help me out this i have a big issue regarding this

Comment: Sometimes certain mirrors get messed up. Try switching to another mirror in the software repository configuration.

Comment: Maybe run `apt-get update` or try with `--fix-missing`?

Comment: Thanks #Mike how can i switch to another mirror in the software repository configuration
Thanks #Biffen but even apt-get update nor working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantal Quetzal, the version of Ubuntu your Mint version is based on, reached end of life earlier this year.

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/

The repos were taken down and are no longer accessible. You will need to update your operating system.

Comment: Thanks @sevenseacat .Can you please tell me how can i now update my machine with my existing data.Will be Grateful to you about this kindness if you give me some of your valueable time

Comment: You are far better to do a reinstall because to go from 12.10 to 14.04 you need to upgrade it to all the releases in between (12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10 -> 14.04), and each upgrade takes a few hours. Just back up your /home directory (that's where all your user's files are) and download the latest linux mint installer to a USB drive and reinstall it. You should choose to format all paritions except /home. If you only have one partition, I recommend booting to the live USB and firing up gparted (you may need to install it) and resize your main partition down and add one to backup your /home.

Answer (score 0):

first run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after that run

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks Nancy .Even not working "sudo apt-get update" this command exactly. Ut said some links not found. a huge list

Comment: is php installed in your system?

Comment: It was due to i was running old version as @sevenseacat says.I am upgrading it now.Thanks for given your time to me.

Comment: YOu are from Bhubaneswar, India ?